# Need help learning lip sync

Tags: animation

Passionate Blender noob (we'll, I have one SOLID year under my belt).  To this point Ive been able to find great online videos explaining the basics of Blender- Ive created a couple decent amateur videos-  Where I am absolutely struggling now is finding tutorials on how to properly lip sync.  I"ve got a great face rig working.  I've seen some okay videos outlining pose-libraries, but no videos really going soup to nuts with the lip synching process. How do you best incorporate your pose library into the lip sync process.. manually? Or is using something like Papagayo the best?  Does anyone know of any great tutorials really breaking down the lip synching prcoesss?  And hopefully one that's CUURENT (2.79,83, 2.9, etc) and in English?   Thanks for any help Blender community!!!!

Comment: the best lip synch tuto I've seen is this one, but it is manual lip synch, not automatic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FIEzAlnVvw

Comment: Hi. [Requests for tutorials are considered off topic here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1). If it requires a full tutorial the question is either [too broad and needs to be narrowed down](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62) to a more specific issue; or it can be solved with a simple web search which you can easily do yourself. Please don't post another question. If you could you rephrase the current one to read more like a direct inquiry about your issue, rather than pointing you to a link, you can [edit] it so it can be reopened.